# Mathematica optimization append table in a loop

Tags: performance, optimization, wolfram-mathematica

I am kinda of new in Mathematica and there are lots of appendto in my code which I think take up a look of time. I know there are some other ways optimize but I cannot really know exactly how to achieve. I think **getBucketShocks** can be improved a lot? Anyone?

```
getBucketShocks[BucketPivots_,BucketShock_,parallelOffset_:0]:=
Module[{shocks,pivotsNb},
shocks={};
pivotsNb=Length[BucketPivots];
If[pivotsNb>1,  
    AppendTo[shocks,LinearFunction[{0,BucketShock},{BucketPivots[[1]],BucketShock},{BucketPivots[[2]],0},BucketPivots[[2]],0},parallelOffset]];

    Do[AppendTo[shocks,LinearFunction[{BucketPivots[[i-1]],0},{BucketPivots[[i]],BucketShock},{BucketPivots[[i+1]],0},{BucketPivots[[i+1]],0},parallelOffset]],{i,2,pivotsNb-1}];

    AppendTo[shocks,LinearFunction[{BucketPivots[[pivotsNb-1]],0},{BucketPivots[[pivotsNb]],BucketShock},{BucketPivots[[pivotsNb]],BucketShock},{BucketPivots[[pivotsNb]],BucketShock},parallelOffset]],    
    If[pivotsNb==1,AppendTo[shocks,BucketShock+parallelOffset&]];
];
shocks];

LinearInterpolation[x_,{x1_,y1_},{x2_,y2_},parallelOffset_:0]:=parallelOffset+y1+(y2-y1)/(x2-x1)*(x-x1);

LinearFunction[p1_,p2_,p3_,p4_,parallelOffset_:0]:=Which[
#<=p1[[1]],parallelOffset+p1[[2]],
#<=p2[[1]],LinearInterpolation[#,p1,p2,parallelOffset],
#<=p3[[1]],LinearInterpolation[#,p2,p3,parallelOffset],
#<=p4[[1]],LinearInterpolation[#,p3,p4,parallelOffset],
#>p4[[1]],parallelOffset+p4[[2]]]&;
```

Comment: several ideas here http://stackoverflow.com/q/39599232/1004168.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can optimize the middle `Do` loop a lot by using some form of `Map` one way or another. At every iteration, you're trying to access 3 adjacent elements of `BucketPivots`. This seems like this would be the easiest to do with `MovingMap`, but you need to jump through a few hoops to get the arguments in the right place. This one is probably the easiest solution:

```
shocks = MovingMap[
  LinearFunction[
    {#[[1]], 0},
    {#[[2]], BucketShock},
    {#[[3]], 0},
    {#[[3]], 0},
    parallelOffset
  ]&,
  BucketPivots,
  2
]
```

As a general principle: if you want to do a `Do` or `For` loop in Mathematica that runs over the `Length` of another list, try to find a way you can do it with a function from the `Map` family (`Map`, `MapIndexed`, `MapAt`, `MapThread`, etc.) and get familiar with those. They are great substitutions for iterations!

After this, the first and last elements of `shocks` you can then add with `AppendTo`.

BTW: here's a free tip. I recommend that in Mathematica you avoid giving variables and functions names that start with a capital (like you did with `BucketPivots`). All of Mathematica's own symbols start with capitals, so if you avoid starting with them yourself, you'll never clash with a build-in function.